# Long Polling Connection ID in SignalR

Tags: signalr, signalr.client

I'm just wondering that in the long polling scenario, if a client will receive a new connection ID when the client reconnects after a timeout (no response from server)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the connection between client and server is lost, client will automatically begin trying to reconnect. If the connection is restored within reconnect timeout period, the `connectionId` stays the same (and `OnReconnected` event is raised on server) - it is considered same SignalR (logical) connection even the underlying physical connection is different. Otherwise, when the reconnect timeout has expired no more automatic attempts will happen, client will have to connect manually again and a new `connectionId` will be generated.

This workflow is *independent* from the transport strategy (long polling, WebSockets, ...).

For more detail, take a look at the [documentation](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/handling-connection-lifetime-events).